# How to read from a file except the last line in C?

Tags: c, file, struct, readfile

I am having a file where i need to read the data and store it into a structure.

```
10001 john
10002 david
10003 randy
10/10/2010 15:50:55 Updated by : Name
```

now for the above file i need to read the data from '10001' & 'john' till '10003' & 'randy' except the last line(End of the file).

How to do it in C?

Update : last line will be dynamic.

Comment: Search google and save us time. Thanks.

Comment: That is why your last line could have been the first line. Then no problem anymore.

Comment: Guillaume: And here I thought that stackoverflow.com was for programming related questions. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

read line by line. When you get `EOF` discard last line.

Edit:

```
while (fgets(line, length, file) && !feof(file))
{
   /* process the line */ 
}
```

Comment: can u help me how to discard the last line.

Comment: My word, how lazy is this guy?

Comment: `while (fgets(line, length, file) && !feof(file)) { /* process the line */ }`

Comment: I am not lazy. I am just a beginner in c and not aware of it, thats why asked. I hope its not bad to ask if i am not clear with the concept. Thanks for your reply and please do not say this to others.

Comment: @Guru it is not about C but about programming in general. see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if the file didn't have that last line? Presumably in some kind of loop, read each line and save it.

You could just add an "if" before you save, checking whether the line matched your "End of the file".

Generally, with these kind of problems, break the problem down into bits you can understand. Then fits the bits together.

You might also want to consider what you should do if the file looks like

```
10001 john
10002 david
Silly line in middle of file
10003 randy
End of the file
10003 mr unexepected
```

Your application should be resilient to weird input.

Comment: Also consider empty lines, especially at the end of a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
char line[81];
FILE *f=fopen("file","rt");

while( fgets(line,sizeof line,f) )
{
int tag1;
char tag2[81];
if( 2==sscanf(line,"%d%80s",&tag1,tag2) )
{
/* do anything */
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int id;
char name[80];

FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

while (fscanf(fp, "%d%s[^n]", &id, name) == 2)
{
   /* do something with id and name */ 
}
```

You don't need to read a line first and then get the data from it. Instead, just read the data you need from the file directly.